# Why does the monthly payment in this program not tally with calculation in Python?

Tags: python, function, input, date-arithmetic

I am trying to write a program that calculates the monthly payment after the
user gives the amount of the loan, the interest rate, and the number of years.

Repex:

Input:

```
Loan = int(input('Enter amount of loan:')) 
#12000
intrate = float(input('Enter interest rate as %:')) 
#6.4
years = int(input('Enter number of years:')) 
#5
i = intrate/1200
b = (1+i)
c = b**(-12*years)
formula = (1-c)
print('Monthly payment:',round(i*Loan/formula,2))
```

Output:

```
Monthly payment: 64.0
```

However, this is incorrect and the final monthly payment should be $234.23

The arithmetic formula before coding the above is as follows:

```
Monthly payment = A*  i / [1-(1+i)**-12n]
```

where i is interest rate,
n is number of years,
A is amount of loan

Comment: I'm getting 234.23 when running your program. Seems like it is working fine

Comment: What's the version of your Python, it produces 234.23 when using Python 3+, I assume you're using Python 2.*, if so, try to add "from \__future__ import division" in the first line of your codes, the division behave differently between 2 and 3.